# Can "same" be postpositive?

Tags: grammar, postpositive

Can we put the sentence "same as" after a noun? For example,

1. He drives the same car as you.
2. He drives the car same as you.

Can we use the latter expression instead of the former?

I seldom see the usage like the latter, but some of my colleagues use it.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. If you require assistance in framing a question, please visit our [Help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) “How to write a good question”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think either sentence is good English. These would be better:

1. He drives the same car as you
2. The car he drives is the same as yours

The "same as yours" needs to modify "car" instead of "drives."